# Why won't my webstream show?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, getusermedia

I tried to test the code below on an android device, it didn't work (the switch button appeared but the camera output didn't.). I then decided to test it on a Mac and it worked (it just showed the camera output and the button, the button didn't do anything because there is no back camera.). Here is my code (the javascript portion of it.):

```
var constraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: {
        width: 1280,
        height: 720
    }
};
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(mediaStream) {
    var video = document.querySelector('#webcam');
    video.srcObject = mediaStream;
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
        video.play();
    };
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
});
var front = false;
document.getElementById('flip-button').onclick = function() {
    front = !front;
};
var constraints = {
    video: {
        facingMode: (front ? "user" : "environment")
    }
};
```

Here's the HTML portion of my code:

```
<video id="webcam">
</video>
<button Id="flip-button">switch
</button>
```

here's the css portion of my code:

```
#webcam {} #flip-button {
    background-color: #202060;
    height: 15%;
    width: 20%;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 40%;
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You got your id wrong. Replace `#webcam` with `#video`.

Or just remove this line:

```
var video = document.querySelector('#webcam');
```

The latter works because ids are implicitly available in global scope for backwards compatibility. Some people frown on this, but it's neat for tidy fiddles.

Some beginner's advice: Always check your browser's web console for errors. Here it said:

```
TypeError: video is null
```

which was the clue that the result from `querySelector` was `null`.

**PS:** You also have two competing definitions of `constraints`, leaving your `facingMode` unused. Lastly, flipping `front` won't do much, unless `front` is used again, which it is not.